# Error: ".Net Framework license compiler" devexpress on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, devexpress, licenses.licx

I am working on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Foundation Server.
I get the following devexpress error when I compile:

Sorun imzası:
- Sorunlu Olay Adı: CLR20r3
- Sorun İmzası 01:  lc.exe
- Sorun İmzası 02:  4.0.30319.1
- Sorun İmzası 03:  4ba1e1e3
- Sorun İmzası 04:  DevExpress.XtraEditors.v11.2
- Sorun İmzası 05:  11.2.8.0
- Sorun İmzası 06:  4f293631
- Sorun İmzası 07:  279
- Sorun İmzası 08:  13
- Sorun İmzası 09:  System.NullReferenceException
- OS Sürümü:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4

```
Exception occurred creating type 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemTextEdit, DevExpress.XtraEditors.v11.2, Version=11.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' System.TypeInitializationException: 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem' tür başlatıcısı özel durum döndürdü. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'DevExpress.Design.v11.2' dosyasını veya derlemesini ya da bağımlılıklarından birini yükleyemedi. Geçersiz işaretçi (HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER)) ---> System.NullReferenceException: Nesne başvurusu bir nesnenin örneğine ayarlanmadı

Exception occurred creating type 'DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonControl, DevExpress.XtraBars.v11.2, Version=11.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' System.TypeInitializationException: 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem' tür başlatıcısı özel durum döndürdü. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'DevExpress.Design.v11.2' dosyasını veya derlemesini ya da bağımlılıklarından birini yükleyemedi. Geçersiz işaretçi (HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER)) ---> System.NullReferenceException: Nesne başvurusu bir nesnenin örneğine ayarlanmadı.   

Exception occurred creating type 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit, DevExpress.XtraEditors.v11.2, Version=11.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' System.TypeInitializationException: 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItem' tür başlatıcısı özel durum döndürdü. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'DevExpress.Design.v11.2' dosyasını veya derlemesini ya da bağımlılıklarından birini yükleyemedi. Geçersiz işaretçi (HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER)) ---> System.NullReferenceException: Nesne başvurusu bir nesnenin örneğine ayarlanmadı.
```

Comment: It would help if you can put translated error messages here

Comment: Did you try to delete the .licx file in your project? It'll be recreated when you'll reopen a form but you don't need it to compile.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: Project is "check out" on my team leader. I didn't delet .licx. Now I have deleted it and have recreated it. Everything is normally.Thanks Adriano:)

Answer (score 1):

I understand Turkish, so i can say check your references of DevExpress dlls and your installation.

Situation can occur because of you use different versions of dlls in development and runtime, make sure they are equal